# Issue processing annotations in Composable functions on Android with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, reflection, annotations, android-jetpack-compose

I'm having trouble processing annotations in Composable functions on my Android project. My goal is to add a custom annotation, let's say @CustomComponent, to my Composable functions and then be able to retrieve these annotated functions at runtime to call them dynamically.

I've tried implementing an annotation processor using the Annotation Processing API (javax.annotation.processing), where I collect the Composable functions annotated with @CustomComponent. However, it seems that my annotation processor is not running correctly during the compilation process. I also tried using reflection but couldn't get the API to work in the Android environment.

Could someone guide me on how I can troubleshoot and fix this issue? Is there any other more effective way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I share a little of the code I developed

My custom annotation

```
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
annotation class CustomComponent
```

an example of use

```
@Composable
@CustomComponent
fun ComposeSample() {
    Text(text = "Sample")
}
```

And the test activity

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Components()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Components() {
    val components = remember { getAllComposablesWithAnnotation(CustomComponent::class.java) }
    LazyColumn {
        items(components.size) { index ->
            components[index].invoke()
        }
    }
}
```

Would anyone know how to create a function `getAllComposablesWithAnnotation` that returns, in this case, the `ComposeSample` function so I can invoke it?

Comment: "be able to retrieve these annotated functions at runtime to call them dynamically" -- that may be a problem, given the code that the Compose Compiler generates around the functions. You might check out other Compose-related annotation processors, like Compose Destinations, to see what they do.

Comment: You might be able to use this - https://github.com/classgraph/classgraph